# lodash: filter objects with value of non empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am new to lodash, and I am writing a line that returns objects that has non-empty array as values (excluding the empty array values);

```
let results = {"1":[1,2,3],"2":[2,4,6],"0":[]};
let filteredResults = _.filter(results, (result) => {return (_.size(_.values(result)) > 0);});
console.log(filteredResults);
```

My expected value of `filteredResults` is: `{'1': [ 1, 2, 3 ], '2': [ 2, 4, 6 ] }`. However I am getting the result of `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 2, 4, 6 ] ]`.

Where are the keys `1` and `2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_.filter` method can accept an object as its first argument, but it will just return an array with the accepted values from the original object. You probably want to use the `_.pickBy` method instead, which will return an object with the key/value pairs that pass the filter:

```
let filteredResults = _.pickBy(results, value => value.length > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and get access to the key and value of each result, evaluate them and push it to the new object. Here's how:

```
let filteredResults = _.reduce(results, (result, value, key) => {
    if (value.length > 0) {
        result[key] = value;
    }
    return result;
}, {});
```